# tar E command line switch

Tags: linux, tar

We're migrating an application from a very old Solaris box over to a relatively newer Linux machine.  I'm having trouble finding an equivalent for a command line option that was used on our old server when running tar on the newer one.  I'm assuming that it is obsolete now, as I don't see anything via man or searching online to indicate why it was done away with... but if anyone has any information, it would be very much appreciated.

The version of tar on the old server was 1.12, and the version on the new server is 1.23.

The command we ran was:

```
tar cEf path-to-tar path-to-tar-up
```

Does anyone know whether this switch is even necessary anymore?  Unfortunately the code using this switch predates my work on the project, so I am unaware of why this particular switch is being used currently.

Comment: Something is amiss: a reference to "1.23" sounds like GNU tar (and "tar --version" would *tell* you what it is), while neither 1.12 of GNU tar nor 1.11.2 (guessing at a typo) recognized a `E` in the options.